# Как использовать отладчик Visual Studio (C# .Net Framework) вне класса Main?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, отладка

Отладчик работает только с классом Main, как сделать так, чтобы он заработал также с другими классами?

Comment: Я новичок в c#, не бейте тапками

Comment: любой видос на ютубе https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZairtpcXTs

Comment: там НЕ уточняется об этом, смотрел два раза

Comment: Breakpoint пробовали в своём классе ставить? Или заходить туда по F11? Классы эти из Main вообще вызываются?

Comment: [Отладка кода в Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019). Покажите код, и расскажите конкретно, как вы выполняли отладку, тогда можно будет что-то вменяемое ответить.

Comment: попробуй запустить студию под администратором